# jni4net : How to pass a Map as parameter to a C# method from Java?

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, jni4net

I'm trying to use jni4net in my Java program to call methods from a `C#` .dll library.

```cs
Bridge.setVerbose(true);
Bridge.init(new File("jni4net.n.w64.v40-0.8.8.0.dll").getAbsoluteFile());

Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(new File("BridgeDemoLibrary.j4n.dll"));

System.out.println();

MyGenerator myGenerator = new MyGenerator();
int result = myGenerator.add(2, 4);
```

It's ok for methods with int or string values as parameters but I also have a `C#` method which takes a `Dictionary<string, int>` object as a parameter and I don't know how to create it within my Java code.

Currenlty I've got the following code:

```cs
// using generic objects doesn't seem to be supported yet...
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Java", 1);
map.put("C#", 2);
map.put("Ruby", 3);

myGenerator.generate_id("10", map);
```

This code doesn't work because the generated `generate_id()` method expects a `system.Object` (which is a class from jni4net) as its second parameter.

So How can I convert my `HashMap` to a `system.Object`?

Regards :)

Comment: Have you found the answer?